# How to enable New Guidelines for Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

Make it easy for users to sign in to your apps and websites using the Apple ID they already have. With privacy and security features built-in, Sign in with Apple is a great way to help users set up an account, sign in, and engage with your app quickly and easily. All accounts are protected with two-factor authentication for superior security, and Apple will not track users’ activity in your app or website.

We’ve updated the App Store Review Guidelines to provide criteria for when apps are required to use Sign in with Apple. Starting today, new apps submitted to the App Store must follow these guidelines. Existing apps and app updates must follow them by April 2020. We’ve also provided new guidelines for using Sign in with Apple on the web and other platforms.

ANY ONE HAVE ANY TUTORIAL FOR THIS?

Comment: Official guidelines and documents can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/).
You can follow along this [tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple) as well.

Comment: ok but need in ionic